# Styling HTML element with attribute inside another class

Tags: css, class, css-selectors

My HTML element  *has an attribute  and the goal is to give a certain style to this element when found inside another class.*

for ex.:

```
<style>
em {color:#ff0000;}
.emClass {color:#ff0000;}
.pClass em {color:#ff0000;}
.pClass .emClass  {color:#ff0000;}
</style>

<p>
    Please <em>red</em> me.
</p>

<p>
    Please <em class="emClass">red</em> me.
</p>

<p class="pClass">
    Please <em>red</em> me.
</p>

<p class="pClass">
    Please <span class="emClass">red</span> me.
</p>

<p class="pClass">
    Please <em class="emClass">orange</em> me.
</p>
```

the goal is to have the text in Orange only in case:

- it is emphasized text
- AND has the "emClass" attribute
- AND it is
  inside another element (paragraph or div) that has the "pClass"
  attribute.

(live example: https://jsfiddle.net/Yatko/Ffkcq/ )

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/Ffkcq/1/

Comment: None of your elements have an `emClass` *attribute*, some of them do have an `emClass` *class-name*, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to update your class to

```
.pClass em.emClass {
    color: orange;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ffkcq/1)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
.pClass em.emClass {color: #ffff00;}
```

Answer (score 2):

***[`JSFiddle Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/Ffkcq/2/)***

You can prefix the class name with the element type. You should target the specific element like this:

```
.pClass em.emClass  {color:orange;}
.pClass span.emClass  {color:red;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/Ffkcq/4/

```
em {

    color:#ff0000;

}

.emClass {

    color:#ff0000;

}

.pClass em {

    color:#ff0000;

}

.pClass .emClass {

    color:#ff0000;

}

.pClass em.emClass {

    color: #FAC802;

}
```